# How to create dynamic instance when java web service client class exist with version number?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, webclient, objectfactory

The web service client jar which we are using getting updated priodically, so the client generated class appears like below,

```
PersonRequet1.java 
PersonRequet2.java
PersonRequet3.java 
StudentRequest1.java
PersonResponse1.java
PersonResponse2.java
PersonResponse3.java
StudentResponse1.java
```

Only PersonRequet1,PersonResponse1 classes exist in the jar initially but now it was updated with 3.

Earlier where ever we invoking service API, we used to instantiated the request and response object like below.

```
 PersonRequet1 person=new PersonRequet1();
 PersonResponse1 resp=new PersonResponse1();
```

Now, the problem is when ever the client jar getting updated with version number, we are forced to use the use the latest version, so we are updating the code like below-

```
 PersonRequet3 person=new PersonRequet3();
 PersonResponse3 resp=new PersonResponse3();
```

Is there is any way to create some config file with key value like below, and instantiate the object reference dynamically or any other good practice with pattern

```
  PersonRequet,3
  PersonResponse,3
  StudentRequest,1
  StudentResponse,1
```

Comment: why would you want to do something like that? are you planning to change every place where one of those objects is used, each time you change versions?

Comment: yes Stultuske, we are calling this API from EJB,Rest and other batchtes.. in all class we are changing the version number when ever its gets updated with newer version...

Comment: ... that's insane. you want a 'simple and logical' solution for this drop the versionnumber.

Comment: no i dont want to drop the version number, i need to create the new instance with version number  PersonRequet3 person=new PersonRequet3();

Comment: what am thinking whenever the client jar gets updating  with new version, thought of having kind of config file with key value... then i need to create instance l something like { Object  ref= new(config.key+config.value) .. i need to look up the config file and get the recent value and create the instance dynamically

Comment: to answer your question: no, that is not possible. you can't "dynamically" declare types that are not in your classpath or anything like that, just because you add it's name somewhere in a config file. Even with a work-around with which your adjustments would be minimal, you still would have to make changes, and it might have side effects you really don't want.

Comment: they are not changing the jar name, they only change the files inside the jar.. any chance Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("myPackage.MyClass");

Comment: Would it not be better to use versioning systems like maven? You could have multiple different web service versions across different projects. Why would you over complicate everything? I pity any dev who would have to support this.

Comment: @CrazySabbath maven does use version numbers, but it isn't a 'versioning system' on itself.

Comment: @Stultuske I thought it was implied that not a stand alone maven. When one tends to use maven, it might be expected that you have a repository which holds different versions of your projects, which are built by maven...sigh

Comment: My point is, in a versioning system you can't change the version in a previous version. Maven doesn't block that, simply because that is not what it is meant for.